# Кэширование изображения

Tags: .htaccess

Ругается pagespeed на то что изображения кешируются на 30 дней хотя я ставил на 6 месяцев. Просьба подсказать

```html
# STARTNITRO
Header unset ETag
Header unset Last-Modified
FileETag None

#CSS JS XML TXT - 6 MONTHS
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15901200, public"
</FilesMatch>

#JPG JPEG PNG GIF SWF SVG - 6 MONTHS
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|svg|JPG|JPEG|PNG|GIF|SWF|SVG)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15901200, public"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 months"
Header set Last-Modified "Wed, 05 Jun 2009 06:40:46 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

#OTF WOFF TTF ICO PDF FLV - 6 MONTHS
<FilesMatch "\.(otf|ico|pdf|flv|woff|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15901200, public"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 months"
</FilesMatch>
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff2
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-woff
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddType application/x-font-eot .eot
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-eot
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\/?(assets).+)\.css$ assets/serveFile.php?t=css&l=4&p=$1&c=15901200 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\/?(assets).+)\.js$ assets/serveFile.php?t=js&l=4&p=$1&c=15901200 [NC,L]
# ENDNITRO
# ����������� � �������� �� ������� ������������
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access 6 months"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7 day"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
# Cache-Control
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
# 30 ����
<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15901200"
</filesMatch>


# 30 ����
<filesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15901200"
</filesMatch>


# 2 ���
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>


# 1 ����
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в моем случае была проблема в хостинге.